# How to iterate array inside array in java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anybody  tell how to iterate array inside array in java script

eg 
Var a =[1,3,[6],7,[8]]

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TRR4n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const inputs = [1,3,[6],7,[8]]

/** loop array */
for (const input of inputs) {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    /** input is array, loop nested array */
    for (const nestedInput of input) {
      /** print item of nested array */
      console.log(nestedInput)
    }
  }
  else {
    /** input is number, print it */
    console.log(input)
  }
}
```

note that: there are so many ways to loop, for..of, forEach, for, while, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive approach for iterating with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array = [1, 3, [6], 7, [8]];

array.forEach(function iter(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach(iter);
        return;
    }
    console.log(a);
});
```